# systemd-nspawn can't auto login

Tags: systemd, login, systemctl, tty, systemd-networkd

I'm trying to config auto login for my nspawn container and I created `/etc/systemd/system/container-getty@.service.d/autologin.conf`
and inside of that I wrote this config:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -f -- \\u' --noclear --keep-baud --autologin username - 115200,38400,9600 $TERM
```

but when I type `machinectl login [CONTAINER NAME]`
it just got stuck in terminal, meaning:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmbWr.png)
What should I do to make this work?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't feel like digging into why it works, but changing the second command to `-/sbin/agetty --noclear --autologin root --keep-baud console 115200,38400,9600 $TERM` did it for me with Debian. Source: https://ixday.github.io/post/systemd_nspawn. Also, apparently that's what the Arch Wiki *used* to say, before switching to the command you tried: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584311. Oh, also the `@`'s not in the examples.